# How to connect SQL Server Compact Edition database .sdf file to ADO Connection

Tags: delphi, sql-server-ce

I am trying to use a small `.sdf` database file created in SQL Server Compact Edition version 4.0 on Delphi application, but I cannot make a connection (ADO Connection) to this database. I have Windows 10 64bit OS, Delphi 10.2

I found tutorial for connection to `.sdf` file created on 3.5 version on this link:
http://slamingcode.blogspot.com/2014/06/connecting-delphi-with-sdf-sql-compact.html

It probably works on `.sdf` files created on 3.5 version, but when I try to connect "my file", I got error saying that database is created on different version and that I need to install specific DB provider.

So, I installed SQL Server Compact Edition v4.0, but it is only available for 64-bit system. After that, I manage to open and view database through LinqPad application (proof that DB provider was installed and that DB is created in version 4 of SSCE). But, in Delphi, there was no DB provider for SSCE v4.0 on ADO connection in the list.

Based on tutorial for setup 3.5 version in the link above, I found proper (I think) registry key for v4.0 (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID{2006C53A-C915-41EA-BAA9-9EAB3A1FBF97}) and added Key "OLE DB Provider" with value "Microsoft SQL Server Compact OLE DB Provider".

Now, I see DB provider in list of providers when I try to make Connection String. But, when I try to use that provider, I got Microsoft Data Link Error:

> Provider is no longer available. Ensure that the provider is installed properly

Is it possible to connect Delphi to a `.sdf` file via ADO connection (or any other) and how?

Comment: A x86 Installer is Also available, and you need more reg entries, see com.ents here: https://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/access-sql-server-compact-4-with-asp.html

Comment: Note that 3.5 and 4.0 can be installed and work side by side. Installing 4.0 does not upgrade 3.5 and uses a different provider name.

Comment: @Brian, thanks for message! Yes, I have 3.5 and 4.0 installed side by side. For 3.5 there are x86 and 64 bit version installed and for 4.0 I could install only 64-bit version because for x86 version I got error message saying that x86 version cannot be installed on 64.bit OS. 
Anyway, I think that provider for SSCE 4.0 is installed propertly because I can open database in LINQPad. But it does not work in Delphi :-(

Comment: @ErikEJ,thank you very much for message! I went trouhgh link you posted and I could not find tips for solving my problem, probably I don't understand this topic good enough :-( I would be very grateful if you could give me some more tips or instructions. And also, sorry for my bad English, it is not my native language...